# Clean arrow function - call generator on multilple elements in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I am trying to use a clean arrow function that calls `yield fork(....)`. I have a lot of places this happens. I am trying to do this:

```
const { ids } = yield take('REQUEST');

// ids is array of numbers [1, 2, 3]

ids.forEach(id => yield fork(requestWorker, id)); ////// this is what im trying to do - this is pseudo-code i know you cant use in non-generators (non-super-star functions)
```

However this does not work and i am having to do:

```
for (const id of ids) {
    yield fork(requestWorker, id);
}
```

instead of the:

```
ids.forEach(id => yield fork(requestWorker, id)); // this is pseudo-code i know you cant use in non-generators (non-super-star functions)
```

Is there a cleaner way then a for-of loop? Like this arrow function method?

Comment: `forEach` does not return something, why is a `yield` inside? besided that yield only works in generators (stared functions).

Comment: @NinaScholz yes thats correct, I dont need to return anything, i just need to trigger a fork on each of these. I purposely wrote the pseudo-code in that arrow function. Im look for something as clean.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what's `fork()`? I don't recognize this as a JS feature. Also, this question has a scent of being an XY-Problem, you explain the proposed solution to an unexplained task.

Comment: @Tomalak it's a generator from redux-saga lib. I didn't think it was important to explain that, but I'll add in the redux-saga tag now. My task is using generator in simple arrow-function-like syntax.

Comment: Why do you think `forEach` would be clean (if it had worked)? `for … of` is much more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi what does idiomatic mean? I looked it up in dictionary but it doesnt make sense in this context to me.

Comment: @Noitidart https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom - more usual, easier to understand (and sometimes, like here, more efficient)

Comment: Ooo thanks Bergi, so it means that if I read it in plain english it makes more sense then a single line of two nested functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could yield another generator

```
function* take(x) {
    var id = /* ... */,
        requesWroker = /* ... */;

    yield* fork(requesWroker, id);
}

var all = [...take('REQUEST')];
```